# to append the file using vi/vim using shell script

Tags: shell, unix, vim, vi

I'm trying to write a shell which would append a '.txt' file with some data(stored in a variable). This i'm trying to do using 'vi'. I know there are other tools too to append the file...but i need to use vi only

I tried below command, but unfortunately this command is not inserting the data to the end of the file.:

`echo $'i{$var}\E:x\n' |vi file.txt`

Comment: Apart of using `vi` you are also using `bash`, right? Why don't use a simple append redirection?

Comment: Why do you need to use `vi` ? Have a look at [I/O redirection](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) in bash if you don't know about it already. In your case, `echo $'i{$var}\E:x\n' >> file.txt` should be enough to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `vi/vim` does not allow you to do a command line edit of the file in-place. Instead you could use its command line equivalent tool `ex`([vi-summary.doc](http://www.csb.yale.edu/userguides/wordprocess/vi-summary.html)) which should be available in any POSIX compliant shell.

```
cat file
foo
bar
```

Now use the `ex` utility in the command line as

```
var=dude
printf '%s\n' '$a' "$var" '.' x | ex file
```

This would edit the file in-place and add the text `dude` at the last line of the file.

```
cat file
foo
bar
dude
```

Comment: Given that OP said they can only use `vi`... it might be interesting to note that `ex` is the same thing as `vi -e`. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this work too

```
var="value" 
printf "$(cat file.txt)\n$var" > newfile.txt
```